# Newly added fields in database(MySql) are not affected after upgrading PHP and CakePHP (2.10.16) version

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have upgraded my PHP and CakePHP version than Newly added fields in database(MySql) are not affected and not show in table schema and not saved/upgraded in database.

1. Web Server: Nginx
2. Database: MySQL
3. CakePHP 2.10.16
4. PHP: 7.3
5. MySQL: 5.7.25
6. Cache: Redis

/*** Not showing all fields ***/

```
pr($this->Model->schema());
```

/*** Not saved Newly added fields ***/

```
$this->Model->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

/*** Not updated Newly added fields ***/

```
$this->Model->updateAll($this->request->data);
```

No error message are show

Comment: clear cache and try again

Comment: Did you resolve this?